# document.getElementById("images").children[0] to a string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The toString() method will output [object HTMLImageElement]. I want a string representation of the the image element `'<img src="..." />'`. outerHTML returns undefined in firefox.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`outerHTML` is not cross-browser.

The easiest way is to clone the element and add it to a parent element, then get the `innerHTML` of that:

```
var outer = document.createElement('outer'),
    child = document.getElementById(“images”).children[0].cloneNode(true);

outer.appendChild(child);

var imgHtml = outer.innerHTML;
```